# How to add days to actual date(Y-m-d)?

Tags: php, html, date

I have a date input on my form. I would like to set the value to the actual date+14days.

I can set the value to the actual date, but how can I add the days to it?

```
<p>Term:<br>
    <input type="date" name="term" id="term" value="<?php print date('Y-m-d'); ?>"</p>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. This one uses `strtotime()` to add the days:

```
<?php print date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+14 days')); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use DateTime class:

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->add(new DateInterval('P14D'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```